# How to get the wrapped value of Binding in init?

Tags: swiftui

How can my code get the wrapped value of a Binding in init()? For some reason it's nil in init(), which means it cant be used to initialize state in init. Thank you

```
import SwiftUI

class Thing {
    var name : String? = "Thingy"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var thing : Thing? = Thing()
    @State var itemToEdit : Thing?
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text(thing!.name!)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        itemToEdit = thing
                        showSheet = true
                    }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                ChildView(itemToEdit:$itemToEdit)
            })
        }
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var itemToEdit : Thing?
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var name: String = ""

    init(itemToEdit: Binding<Thing?>) {
        self._itemToEdit = itemToEdit
        print("itemToEdit \(self.itemToEdit)") // A: itemToEdit is nil here
        //name = self.itemToEdit.unsafelyUnwrapped.name!
    }
     
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        print("itemToEdit!.name ", itemToEdit!.name) // B: itemToEdit is not nil here
                        itemToEdit!.name = self.name
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your model should probably be a struct, not a class. Then, use `item` instead of `isPresented`

Answer (score 1):

It appears `nil` in `init` because when you set `itemToEdit = thing`, the value of `itemToEdit` doesn't actually change immediately. Instead, what happens is SwiftUI notices a change in `@State`, and redraws your view. only after the redraw can you observe a different value.

You can do the initialisation of `name` in `onAppear`. By then the view would have been redrawn.

```
.onAppear {
    name = itemToEdit?.name ?? ""
}
```

That said, `@State` doesn't work well with reference types. After setting `Thing.name` in `ChildView`, `ContentView` will not know about the change. You should make `Thing` an `Identifiable` `struct` instead.

```
struct Thing: Identifiable {
    var name : String? = "Thingy"
    let id = UUID() // or your own implementation
}
```

I'm also not sure why you have an extra `itemToEdit` state when you only have one item. The `ChildView` will change `itemToEdit`, but your `Text` is displaying `thing`, which is different.

Either way, it seems like you probably have a list of `Thing`s and want to make a list of editable items (?) In that case, use [the overload of `ForEach.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6oy5i) that takes a `Binding`.

```
ForEach($things) { thing in
    Text(thing.wrappedValue.name ?? "")
        .onTapGesture {
            showSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            // ChildView should take a Binding<Thing>
            ChildView(itemToEdit: thing)
        }
}
```

Now, because you are passing the binding given to you in the `ForEach`, you can initialise `name` in `ChildView.init` in your original way.